# where to add the import command

Tags: javascript, laravel, tensorflow

i am trying to implement a toxicity js in my laravel project 
i am using this library 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow-models/toxicity

but when ever i run it i get this error in console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: toxicity is not defined
```

my code looks like this atm

View

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

myjs.js

```
//import * as toxicity from '../../node_modules/@tensorflow-models/toxicity'; //doesnt work
//import * as toxicity from '@tensorflow-models/toxicity'; //doesnt work
$(document).ready(function() {
    const threshold = 0.9;

// Load the model. Users optionally pass in a threshold and an array of
// labels to include.
    toxicity.load(threshold).then(model => {
        const sentences = ['you suck'];

        model.classify(sentences).then(predictions => {
            // `predictions` is an array of objects, one for each prediction head,
            // that contains the raw probabilities for each input along with the
            // final prediction in `match` (either `true` or `false`).
            // If neither prediction exceeds the threshold, `match` is `null`.

            console.log(predictions);
            /*
            prints:
            {
              "label": "identity_attack",
              "results": [{
                "probabilities": [0.9659664034843445, 0.03403361141681671],
                "match": false
              }]
            },
            {
              "label": "insult",
              "results": [{
                "probabilities": [0.08124706149101257, 0.9187529683113098],
                "match": true
              }]
            },
            ...
             */
        });
    });
});
```

i think the problem is that i do not know where should i include this line in laravel

```
import * as toxicity from '@tensorflow-models/toxicity';
```

if i include this in the js file it gives an error that says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

Comment: Why have you commented the import out? You usually would place imports at the very top of the JS file too.

Comment: read the last part please

Answer (score 0):

To check, are you using something like Laravel Mix / webpack to compiler your code? So with Laravel Mix you'd run your file through the `js()` helper, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#working-with-scripts

If you're using the default Laravel setup, you could add this into the file at https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/js/bootstrap.js

If you look at the highlighted lines at https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/js/bootstrap.js#L32-L41 there is an example commented out where Laravel "Echo" library is imported in a similar manner to your own.

Comment: In that case, the example files I linked demonstrate how to import NPM packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to the app.js file in resource/js folder
Then in your terminal run the command

```
npm run dev
```

then try using it again. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

okay so i managed to fix this error by going into the 
bootstrap.js file and adding this

```
window.toxicity = require('@tensorflow-models/toxicity');
```

and then running

```
npm run dev
```